# how to get promises in angular2

Tags: angular, promise

I don't know exactly what I need, but my situation is as follow.

I have a function to check auth status as below:

```
 authCheck() {
        if (localStorage.getItem('auth_key')) {
            if (!this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(localStorage.getItem('auth_key'))) // check if its not expired
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else {
                if (localStorage.getItem('refresh_key')) { // check if refresh key is present 
                    // renew auth key 
                    this.refreshLogin()
                        .subscribe(
                        Ttoken => {
                            localStorage.setItem("auth_key", Ttoken.access_token);
                            localStorage.setItem("refresh_key", Ttoken.refresh_token);
                            return 0;
                        },
                        Error => {
                            localStorage.removeItem("refresh_key");
                            console.log(Error);
                            return 1;

                        })
                    //----------------------end of refresh method
                } else { console.log("no refresh key"); return 1;}
            }
        } else { console.log("no auth key");  return 1;}
    }
```

And I am calling it as this `let result = this._authervice.authCheck();`
but it works if `result = 0` otherwise it sends me `undefined`.

How can I get promise value 0 or 1 or how to call this function so it can wait to finish the http function and return me the exact value and not undefined?

Comment: You could use `return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> { //have code here; //do reject & resolve to completed/reject promise  })`

Comment: @PankajParkar you mean `let result = new promise((resolve,reject) =>{this._authervice.authCheck();});`??

Comment: check the answer I've added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Promise` of ES6 & `resolve & reject` promise based on your code logic

```
authCheck() {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> { 
      //have code here; 
      //resolve(dataToReturn);
      //do reject & resolve to completed/reject promise 
      //reject('Error message');
   })
}

let result = 0; //default value;
authCheck().then(
  (data)=> result = data, //success
  (error)=> result = error //error
);
```

**Code**

```
 authCheck() {
   return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (localStorage.getItem('auth_key')) {
       if (!this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(localStorage.getItem('auth_key'))) // check if its not expired
       {
         resolve(0);
       } else {
         if (localStorage.getItem('refresh_key')) { // check if refresh key is present 
           // renew auth key 
           this.refreshLogin()
             .subscribe(
             Ttoken => {
               localStorage.setItem("auth_key", Ttoken.access_token);
               localStorage.setItem("refresh_key", Ttoken.refresh_token);
               resolve(0);
             },
             Error => {
               localStorage.removeItem("refresh_key");
               console.log(Error);
               reject(1);

             })
           //----------------------end of refresh method
         } else {
           console.log("no refresh key");
           reject(1);
         }
       }
     } else {
       console.log("no auth key");
       reject(1);
     }
   })
 }
```

Comment: hey but this one is working too `let result = new promise((resolve,reject) =>{this._authervice.authCheck();});` is it good practice though??

Comment: no its not working i had removed code, , wait i will try your answer and let you know

Comment: i think i am doing something wrong as per your instructions   `return 0; to resolve (0)` and `return 1; to reject (1) ` right??

Comment: If you meant that 0 is success & 1 is for failing the request then its correct

Comment: may be i am doing something wrong could you show me in my code how to use it??

Comment: @noobProgrammer you should also bind error function to get rejected value.